# How to Stealth Port 0 on a router

Tags: router, port, modem, gateway, ports

My Sagemcom F@st 3868 cable gateway (modem-router combo) has four devices on its LAN ports: a PC, a Hardware Firewall, a Cable TV Switch and a VoIP Adapter. The `GRC Shields UP!` test showed several ports closed but not stealthed.

I have forwarded all the closed ports found by `Shields UP!` to the Hardware Firewall, which has stealthed them. However, Port 0 is still not stealthed and there is no way to forward it to the hardware firewall. The gateway also has a built-in firewall but even setting it to high does not resolve the issue, probably because the RTP and SIP ports are forwarded to the VoIP Adapter, which requires them to work.

Any suggestions for how to Stealth Port 0 will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why exactly do you need traffic on port 0? It's a reserved port not used by regular TCP or UDP traffic and blocked by most ISPs anyway.

Comment: What is really the point of trying to 'stealth' the ports? If they're closed, they're closed -- there's no service listening on them already. _(The irony of GRC's website talking about how "companies are already exploiting the fear of Internet intrusion"...)_

Comment: A host (like your router) by itself cannot _really_ achieve stealth. There is only two ways to pretend you’re not there: The _upstream router_ must respond with ICMP Host unreachable OR the IP address must not be announced in BGP.

Answer (score 2):

If most ports are "stealthed" and the rest/one of them is "closed" you are good to go, since virtually no attack on your system will be possible. The difference between stealthed and blocked - in layman's terms - is that on stealth no response is sent back to the probe, with closed ports the probe will get the response "closed". There might be some added benefit to stealth the port but for most scenarios they don't matter anyway, so I wouldn't worry about it too much.

If you have a different reason to stealth the ports you need to check what `GRC Shields UP!` is actually detecting. As I wrote in my comment `port 0` is blocked by most ISPs and I assume that is the block `GRC Shields UP!` is actually detecting. In this case there is nothing you can do about it except asking you ISP to use a "stealth" instead of a "block" (you might need to explain what you mean, since "stealthed port" is not official network terminology). For further information this this question ["GRC Shields Up test - are stealth ports good?"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147770/grc-shields-up-test-are-stealth-ports-good) might be helpful and if you search you'll find much more. I would suggest to read up on `port 0` as well, since it's not a "regular port".

Answer (score 0):

The term "Stealth".for ports, is problematic.

Stealth is a term made up by Steve Gibson(who wrote a port scanner called "shields up").

He got a lot of criticism for that "stealth" claim (among others), and regarding that "stealth" claim he got criticism for it because he suggested that if a port comes up as closed you are "not secure".

If a port doesn't respond to a test to see if it's open or closed, then nmap would refer to it as "filtered".  Steve Gibson refers to it as "stealth" and wrongly suggests that "closed" is insecure.

Comment: But it's worth to note that the term "stealth" is used in similar context in other sources as well. I remember to read about stealth in combination with the Windows firewall, there is "TCP Stealth" etc. But I also agree (partly) with the criticism towards Steve Gibson's work.

Comment: @Albin maybe the proposal of the  idea of "TCP Stealth", came from him! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Stealth   I notice the year is long long after his "shields up" website.. I dno't know if they adopted it.. hopefully they won't adopt his "nanoprobes" term!

Comment: yeah or maybe the name was "inspired" by his terminology

Comment: well, hopefully they reviewed the old grcsucks.com  and got warned to be careful re anything inspired by him!

Comment: IMHO it is easier to kill the bearer of bad news than to hear it and fix its source. The fact is that my cable router did stealth (or filter) Port 0 before I forwarded its RTP and SIP ports to my VoIP Adapter, as instructed by the VoIP service provider. Moreover, when I had a different ISP with a DSL gateway, it did pass the Shields UP! stealth test, including Port 0. With the DSL gateway I did not need to forward any ports, just to reset the VoIP adapter, which was automatically detected and good to go. So the problem seems to be with the gateway (router) and not with the Shields UP! test.

Comment: @groucho43 I don't think you are understanding this.   Nmap for example uses the word "filtered" instead of "stealth". If you had seen one test say "filtered" and another say "closed", would you say there was a probelm with your gateway/router?

Answer (score 0):

Tried to reply in Norton Forums but was unable. Anyway...

I have an Asus router, the AC2900/RT-86U. In the router settings there is an option to forward "IPTV" and shows the allowable port as "0". Simply delete it and save the setting. As you already know, Port 0 is actually a re-direction port, basically telling apps to direct to another port. ShieldsUp! first showed Port 0 as closed (but 'stealthed', go figure) and deleting the digit from the IPTV port dialog box "stealthed" it completely, removing it from any use. If your router does not have IPTV capability then I'd suggest some other user service or proxy is pointing to it. Good luck and I hope this helps.

Comment: Port 0 is a reserved port and not used for regular TCP or UDP connection. I never heard that it's used for IPTV. I think you are mistaking the so called "UDP proxy" with a port. If 0 is set, it's not the port, it's the disabling option. Do you have any sources?